# Prove that function has a saddle point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The following was a question on a recent analysis exam I took. We had to make this without a CAS.

> Prove that 
>   $$f(x,y)=\sin(x^2-y^2)-(x^2-y^2)\cos(x^2+y^2)-\dfrac{(x^2-y^2)y^4}{3} $$
>   has a saddle point in $(0,0)$.

The Hessian test is indecisive: according to Wolfram Alpha it has a zero on the diagonal.

So I try to find two curves, on one of which $f$ has a local maximum and on one of which $f$ has a local minimum.

It is pretty easy to prove that $g(x):=f(x,0)=\sin(x^2)-x^2\cos(x^2)$ has a local minimum in $x=0$. Indeed, $g'(x)=2x^3 \sin(x^2)$ and for $0<|x|<\sqrt{\pi/2}$, we have $\sin(x^2)>0$, so $g'$ changes sign from $-$ to $+$ in $x=0$. Hence, $f$ has a local minimum in $(0,0)$ along $y=0$.

After some playing in Desmos, I found that
$$h(x):=f(x,2x)=-\sin(3x^2)+3x^2\cos(5x^2)+16x^6$$
has a local *maximum* in $x=0$. Hence, $f$ apparently has a local maximum in $(0,0)$ along the line $y=2x$.

However, I can't prove this by hand from the expression for the derivative: $h'(x)=-6x\cos(3x^2) +6x\cos(5x^2)-30x^3 \sin(5x^2)+96x^5$. Also, I would have never been able to come up with this on the exam.

Is there any slick way to prove $f$ has a saddle point in $(0,0)$ **by hand**? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is Hessian at $x=y=0$?

Comment: I have read it, but note that having $0$ on diagonal does not mean that the Hessian matrix is indecisive. Note $f(x,y)=xy$ for example.

Comment: What I mean by indecisive is that we can't conclude anything from it. If all the eigenvalues are positive, we have a local minimum, if all the eigenvalues are negative a local maximum and if one eigenvalue is positive and the other one is negative we have a saddle point. Here, one is zero so we can't say deduce anything from the Hessian matrix.

Comment: the idea is to consider higher order taylor expansions of your function, and investigate the resulting polynomial. I'll try to elaborate more when I have time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before addressing your actual question, let me briefly outline how the various derivative tests are proven in the single variable case. Suppose $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$; then, we look for the first non-zero derivative of $f$ (assuming that not all derivatives are zero). So, suppose $f^{(k)}(a) \neq 0$ ($k \geq 2$), while $f'(a) = \dots = f^{(k-1)}(a) = 0$. Then, by Taylor's theorem,
\begin{align}
f(\xi) - f(a) &= \dfrac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} (\xi - a)^k + \mathcal{O}(|\xi - a|^{k+1}).
\end{align}
In other words, to study the local behaviour of $f$ near the point $a$, since the error term is small (in the big OH sense I wrote above), all we need to do is study the properties of the $k^{th}$ order polynomial $\dfrac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(\xi - a)^k$. Thus, we get a simple sufficient condition for determining the type of critical point:

- If $k$ is even and $f^{(k)}(a) > 0$ then $f$ has a local minimum at $a$.
- If $k$ is even and $f^{(k)}(a) < 0$ then $f$ has a local maximum at $a$.
- If $k$ is odd then $f$ has a saddle point (increases in one direction, decreases in the other) at $a$.

To see this, just sketch the graph of that polynomial; it will be almost obvious. In the multivariable case, there is a similar statement, but because of the higher number of possibilities, the statement is not as exhaustive.

---

So, for your given function, simply calculate the first few terms in the truncated Taylor polynomial:
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= \left[(x^2 - y^2) - \dfrac{(x^2 - y^2)^3}{3!} + \mathcal{O}((x^2 - y^2)^5) \right]\\
&- (x^2 - y^2)\left[1 - \dfrac{(x^2 + y^2)^2}{2!} + \mathcal{O}((x^2 + y^2)^4) \right]\\
&- \dfrac{(x^2 - y^2)y^4}{3} \\
&= \dots \\
&= \dfrac{(x^2 - y^2)x^2(x^2 + 4y^2)}{3} + \mathcal{O}\left( \lVert(x,y) \rVert^{10}\right)
\end{align}
So, if we plug in $y=0$, we find that
\begin{align}
f(x,0) &= \dfrac{x^6}{3} + \mathcal{O}(|x|^{10})
\end{align}
which implies $0$ is a local minimum for this single variable function. If we now plug in $y = 2x$, then
\begin{align}
f(x,2x) &= -17 x^6 + \mathcal{O}(|x|^{10}),
\end{align}
which has a local maximum at the origin. Since by restricting the function $f$ to two different paths gave two different types of extrema, it follows that the origin is a saddle point for $f$.

Comment: This is answer is very well written and helpful, thanks!! There is just a small typo, in the Taylor expansion for $f$, the first $+$ on the second line should be a $-$.

Comment: @rae306 Thanks for spotting that. I was also missing the constant term $f(a)$ in the Taylor expansion lol